# How to show HTML comments in Firebug?

Tags: firebug

I want to know how to show HTML comments within the *HTML* panel of Firebug. I am using a Knockout.js template including HTML comments. And it would be helpful if I could see these comments in Firebug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can enable the display of comments within the [*HTML* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel) via the option *Show Comments* inside the options menu:

[image: 'Show Comments' option within the HTML panel]

You can open that menu by clicking on the little arrow within the panel tab or by right-clicking the panel tab.

Comment: That is what I want. It really helps.

Comment: And to edit, mouse over the comment, right click > edit node.

Comment: Or just click it.